# Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle ошибка в строке if (firebaseUser != null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите решить проблему, только пожалуйста по пальцам, ибо я в этом мало чего понимаю:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle Process: com.example.blum, PID: 22797 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at Notifications.MyFirebaseMessaging.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessaging.java:30)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:74)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:44)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:27)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:17)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:43)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

мой MyFirebaseMessaging:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int i = 0;
        if (j > 0) {
            i = j;
        }

        noti.notify(i, builder.build());
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseIdService:

```
public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            updateToken(refreshToken);
        }
    }

    private void updateToken(String refreshToken) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
        Token token = new Token(refreshToken);
        reference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())` а если `sended == null` ? Вы у null можете метод `equals` вызвать?

Comment: @ArchDemon Перепробовал различные варианты... Ничего не помогает. Пробовал использовать [https://github.com/Mohammed187/ChatApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/chatapp/Notifications/MyFirebaseMessaging.java#L77] такой код... не помогло

Comment: а проверять в `if` `sented != null` религия не позволяет?